# Scala resolving futures in try block

Tags: scala

Consider the following Scala `try catch finally` example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Test extends App {

  try {
    val futureResponses = Future(List("200", "200", "500", "600"))
    println("in TRY block...")
    futureResponses.map{responses =>
      responses.forall(_ == 200) match {
        case true => println("Successfully Finished the Requets")
        case false => println("Failed when fetching requests")
      }}
  }
  catch {
    case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
  }
  finally {
    println("finally thing...")
  }
}
```

`finally` block is executed before resolving futures in Try block and outputs

```
in TRY block...
finally thing...
```

How to wait until try block resolves futures

Answer (score 1):

you don't really need `try` block there, which is not recommended in functional programming. you can use `future.onComplete`. If you really need use `Try {}` instead.

Example for successful future with `onComplete`,

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala>     Future(List("200", "200", "500", "600")).map { responses =>
     |       responses.forall(_ == 200) match {
     |         case true => println("Successfully Finished the Requets")
     |         case false => println("\nFailed when fetching requests")
     |       }
     |     } onComplete (res => println(s"finally thing... + $res"))

Failed when fetching requests
finally thing... + Success(())
```

Example, when future fails,

```
scala>     Future(List("200", "200", "500", "600")).map { responses =>
     |       responses.map(r => r.toInt / 0)
     |     } onComplete (res => println(s"finally thing... + $res"))

scala> finally thing... + Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
```